# How to create a list of unassigned class objects

Tags: c#, list, oop

I need to call class objects in an order.

Class1 should be initalized first.

It will do it's job.

A value will be returned.

If value is true Class2 will be initialized. Else no more class will be initialized.

Here is psuedo code what i am trying to achieve.

```
List<Classes> myClassList = new List<Classes>();

myClassList.add(Class1);
myClassList.add(Class2);
//add more classes

foreach(Class currentClass in myClassList){
    initialize currentClass

    if(!currentClass.doSomething){
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        currentClass.dispose();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: The line `initialize currentClass`, is that pseudo-code?

Comment: Yes. That line should be replaced with a real code which will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to create an abstraction (In this case we'll use an interface) in order to make a list of classes, all of the classes should implement this interface. And then you're not going to do a list of Class but a list of this interface.

I'll provide you a simple example:

```cs
    // The abstraction
    public interface IClass : IDisposable {
        bool DoSomething();
        void Initialize();
    }

    // First class
    public class Class1 : IClass {
        public void Dispose() {
            // Dispose stuff
        }

        public bool DoSomething() {
            //perform operations
            return true; // the result of your operations
        }

        public void Initialize() {
            // Do the initialization
        }
    }

    // Second class
    public class Class2 : IClass {
        public void Dispose() {
            // Dispose Stuff
        }

        public bool DoSomething() {
            //perform operations
            return true; // the result of your operations
        }

        public void Initialize() {
            // Do the initialization
        }
    }

    // Other classes ...
    // ...

    // Your method to perform the operations with a list of classes
    List<IClass> myClassList = new List<IClass>();

    myClassList.Add(new Class1());
    myClassList.Add(new Class2());
    //Adds more classes

    foreach (IClass currentClass in myClassList) {
        currentClass.Initialize();
        if (!currentClass.DoSomething()) {
            break;
        } else {
            currentClass.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Although I used an interface you could accomplish the same thing using an abstract class (but you should use it only if the classes share some common behaviour, if not it's better to use an interface).

As other have mentioned you could use reflection and accomplish the same thing, but since you've said there are a lot of classes this approach would perform better cause reflection is quite more expensive :)

Comment: I think my question is not clear. I don't want to initialize objects before the right time. In the foreach loop they should be initialized one by one. In your answer you initialized everything while adding to the list. This is not I need. I will consider your note about performance. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: If you don´t do anything in the constructor and move the actual initialization of the object and its data to the Initialize method there should not be any problem with initializing the objects using the new keyword. With the new you're just gonna create the references to the objects but will not have any data on them.

Comment: Ah, that's good. To be sure, asking again. Assume that I have 100 classes. If I don't do anything inside their constructors. It won't cause any performance problems right? By the way I am just initializing a list of methods inside the constructors of the classes. Each have +/- 10 methods.

Comment: What do you mean by Initializing methods? Do you call the methods inside the constructor? If that's the case now I can understand why you're worried about the initialization...

Comment: I have a List<Func<returnVal>> myFuncs in baseclass. Each class derived from that base class adds some fuctions to that list in their constructors. So I can foreach all the functions. If one fails the next one does not be invoked.

Comment: I get it... If you move that functionality to the initialize method there should be no problem with the performance. You should also Clear the list when the job is done.

Comment: I can move that process to a function instead of doing it in the constructor. If initializing objects with new keyword does not cost any performance or memory problems. You said there will be no performance problems and I assume there will be no memory problems also. Am i correct? Thank you for great help.

Comment: You're welcome!
Just to leave things a little bit clearer: when you create an object with the new keyword you're allocating a space in memory that holds the reference to that object, but if that object is not doing anything and it's not holding any data the space on memory is going to be really small so it should have no impact in the performance or in the memory consumption of your application.
Good luck on your project

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options :

1. make `List<Classes> myClassList` a list of dynamic objects
   `List<dynamic> myClassList` , this way you can add different type of
   classes to this list and can easily access there operation (Methods)
   at run time

   the above option is the easier option to get going but not the best option if you want to consider performance,design
2. it seems that your classes have something in common , they all have
   the doSomething operation , so why don't we group these types under
   an interface (ICanDoSomething) or parent class depending on the
   situation that has the `doSomething` Method , and your
   `List<Classes> myClassList` becomes `List<ICanDoSomething>
   myClassList`

Comment: Yes I am using a baseclass. Didn't mention it to make it simple. However adding something to List<ICanDoSomething> seems not possible without initializing the objects first. I don't want to initialize them because I have a huge list of classes. Initializing them before assigning a list will cause some performance problems. Or am I wrong?

Comment: you can create an object of this base class at run time using reflection 
BaseClass baseObj =  Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass));
then baseObj .doSomething()

Comment: @vaallez, "_because I have a huge list of classes_" Something about this sounds terribly wrong and very fishy. I don't dare asking how you got into a situation of having/needing a huge list of classes (types). Something, something, question and rethink the design decisions you made in your programming project. If you talk about objects, okay. You can create thousands of objects without major problems. If those objects have to hold some "bigger" amount of data at some point, only create/load/produce the data on demand (for example, only when such methods are called that actually need this data)

Comment: @elgonzo I am creating a website test automation. Each page or big functionality represented with classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store a `List` of `Type` and add your class types, like:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
types.Add(Class1.GetType());
types.Add(Class2.GetType());
```

Then you can instantiate a class of a given `Type` using `Activator` or reflection.

Example:

```
foreach(var type in types){
  // creates an instance using the default constructor
  object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

  //calls a given method
  MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
  method.Invoke(instance, null);
}
```

This creates an instance of `type` using the default constructor and calls a specific method.

Comment: Ok this seems useful however GetType method is not available if I don't initialize the object first.